# Is there a way of using an Iframe tag for this example

Tags: html

I've created a block which his position is fixed.
my goal is to let the user a scroll down option in the block so he could see all the data that displays in the block, I know that iframe lets the user a scroll down, up and a scroll left and right option so the user can watch all the data. is it possiable to do the same thing but instead of watching a different website. it will display the code instead. for example `<iframe>code</iframe>`

Comment: Why do you want an iframe? Just use `<code>...</code>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you properly, using an iframe is a bad idea if you are loading content from the same URL. Perhaps you could use CSS to control the element's scroll to do what you want, for example using

```
overflow: auto;
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hhox2uc1/

Comment: Brilliant, would you consider marking this as the answer. Thanks